# How to debug using printf an assembly code of linux kernel

Tags: c, assembly, linux-kernel, arm

[This](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/arm/kernel/head.S) is the file that I am trying to debug by putting printf/printk statements.

The code is assembly.

```
 79         __HEAD
 80 ENTRY(stext)
 81  ARM_BE8(setend be )                    @ ensure we are in BE8 mode
 82 
 83  THUMB( adr     r9, BSYM(1f)    )       @ Kernel is always entered in ARM.
 84  THUMB( bx      r9              )       @ If this is a Thumb-2 kernel,
 85  THUMB( .thumb                  )       @ switch to Thumb now.
 86  THUMB(1:                       )
 87 
 88 #ifdef CONFIG_ARM_VIRT_EXT
 89         bl      __hyp_stub_install
 90 #endif
 91         @ ensure svc mode and all interrupts masked
 92         safe_svcmode_maskall r9
 93 
 94         mrc     p15, 0, r9, c0, c0              @ get processor id
 95         bl      __lookup_processor_type         @ r5=procinfo r9=cpuid
 96         movs    r10, r5                         @ invalid processor (r5=0)?
 97  THUMB( it      eq )            @ force fixup-able long branch encoding
 98         beq     __error_p                       @ yes, error 'p'
 99 
100 #ifdef CONFIG_ARM_LPAE
101         mrc     p15, 0, r3, c0, c1, 4           @ read ID_MMFR0
102         and     r3, r3, #0xf                    @ extract VMSA support
103         cmp     r3, #5                          @ long-descriptor translation table format?
104  THUMB( it      lo )                            @ force fixup-able long branch encoding
105         blo     __error_lpae                    @ only classic page table format
106 #endif
107 
108 #ifndef CONFIG_XIP_KERNEL
109         adr     r3,
```

I simply want to put some messages to console from this file. This code is for ARM.

I tried using printk in such code blocks but it fails to compile.

Any suggestions?

Comment: This is the very top of the kernel entry point - you don't even have a _stack_ yet. You could probably borrow a couple of spare registers to dump bytes to a hardcoded UART address, but `printk` is pretty much out of the question until you hit `start_kernel`. However, if your bootloader has a `printf` implementation and has left you a usable SP, you might be able to use that at this point if you can figure out the right address to call.

Answer (score 4):

The answer is given in [**ARM booting FAQ**](http://www.arm.linux.org.uk/mailinglists/faq.php#f6).  You need to enable the config menu item *Kernel Hacking|Kernel low-level debugging functions*.  For instance, the code [`__error_p`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/arm/kernel/head-common.S#L192) will then display something on your console UART.  For instance, [elinux.org's Debugging by printing](http://elinux.org/Debugging_by_printing#Using_CONFIG_DEBUG_LL_and_printascii.28.29_.28ARM_only.29) shows an error message when the kernel can not match your machine id. <sup>See: [ARM booting documentation](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/arm/Booting)</sup>

**DEBUG_LL** creates the function `extern void printascii(char *);` which you can also instrument `vprintk_emit()` with.

```
--- a/kernel/printk/printk.c
+++ b/kernel/printk/printk.c
@@ -1483,6 +1483,8 @@ static size_t cont_print_text(char *text, size_t size)
        return textlen;
 }

+extern void printascii(char*);
+
 asmlinkage int vprintk_emit(int facility, int level,
                            const char *dict, size_t dictlen,
                            const char *fmt, va_list args)
@@ -1541,6 +1543,7 @@ asmlinkage int vprintk_emit(int facility, int level,
         * prefix which might be passed-in as a parameter.
         */
        text_len = vscnprintf(text, sizeof(textbuf), fmt, args);
+       printascii(text);

        /* mark and strip a trailing newline */
        if (text_len && text[text_len-1] == '\n') {
```

This and the kernel command line **initcall_debug** will be useful to diagnose boot issue.

If you platform doesn't support the **DEBUG_LL**, it is fairly easy to implement the polled UART routines needed to support it.

Normally, `printk()` is buffered during early boot and doesn't actually print out until the console driver is active.  So, without patching the `vprintk_emit()`, you can crash/halt anywhere before the UART driver runs and see nothing with a normal configuration.

For debugging of *head.S* and the like, you need to do this in assembler.  The `error_p` implementation has some sample code and here is another,

```
 #ifdef CONFIG_DEBUG_LL
         /* Save some registers? */
         adr     r0, prefix
         bl      printascii
         mov     r0, r9
         bl      printhex8
         adr     r0, tail
         bl      printascii
         b       1f
 prefix: .asciz  "\nTrace 1 gives "
 tail:   .asciz  "\n"
 1:  /* Perhaps halt here, due to register clobbers */
 #endif
```

You are limited in the use of registers depending on the context in *head.S*.  Often the only issue with this code is you didn't do something described in the [ARM booting documentation](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/arm/Booting).

You may also use the macros directly which are defined in [*arch/arm/include/debug*](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/arch/arm/include/debug).  The macros are,

- `addruart` - get the addresses of the uarts to parameter 1 (phys), 2 (virt), (3rd is a tmp for macro).
- `senduart` - write character param 1 to address (virtual or physical).
- `waituart` - parm 1 (tmp), param 2 address (virt or phys). Ready?
- `busyuart` - parm 1 (tmp), param 2 address (virt or phys). Empty?

You can see the API in use in the implementation of [`printasii()`](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/arch/arm/kernel/debug.S).

```
ENTRY(printascii)
        addruart_current r3, r1, r2   @ phys address to r3
        b   2f
1:      waituart r2, r3   @ ready (r2 is tmp, r3 is phys address)
        senduart r1, r3   @ transmit r1 character
        busyuart r2, r3   @ wait for character to finish tx.
        teq r1, #'\n'
        moveq   r1, #'\r' @ insert carriage return if new line.
        beq 1b
2:      teq r0, #0    @ NULL pointer?
        ldrneb  r1, [r0], #1  @ next char
        teqne   r1, #0        @ end of string?
        bne     1b            @ send another.
        mov pc, lr
ENDPROC(printascii)
```

In the assembler of *head.S* and others, you can use the macros with various register arguments to avoid clobbers of in-use registers such as `r0-r3`.  They are usually available for use and `printascii()` can be called directly.

Comment: Toggling I/O lines with an LED or scope on the line and/or JTAG, etc are alternatives.  If you have *TrustZone* working, you can debug the start up from the *Secure world*.