# How does the ARM Linux kernel map console output to a hardware device on boot?

Tags: linux-kernel, console, arm, qemu, device-tree

I'm currently struggling to determine how I can get an emulated environment via QEMU to correctly display output on the command line. I have an environment that displays perfectly well using the `virt` reference board, a `cortex-a9`CPU, and the 4.1 Linux kernel cross-compiled for ARM. However, if I swap out the 4.1 kernel for 2.6 or 3.1, suddenly I can no longer see console output.

While solving this issue is my main goal, I feel like I lack a critical understanding of *how* Linux and the hardware initially integrate before userspace configurations via boot scripts and whatnot have a chance to execute. I am aware of the device tree, and have a loose understanding of how it works. But the issue I ran into where a different kernel version broke console availability entirely confounds me. Can someone explain how Linux initially maps console output to a hardware device on the ARM architecture?

Thank you!

Comment: [Debug linux kernel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24302830/how-to-debug-using-printf-an-assembly-code-of-linux-kernel) and similar at [NXP forum](https://community.nxp.com/thread/419668)  Mainly `printascii` is a polled mode facility to print a string.  `printk` itself does not print instantly and crashes my occur before anything is output especially before an interrupt infrastructure, etc is complete in the kernel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer depends quite a bit on which kernel version, what config options are set, what hardware, and also possibly on kernel command line arguments.

For modern kernels, the answer is that it looks in the device tree blob it is passed for descriptions of devices, some of which will be serial ports, and it initializes those. The kernel config or command line will specify which of those is to be used for the console. For earlier kernels, especially if you go all the way back to 2.6, use of device tree was less universal, and for some hardware the boot loader simply said "this is a versatile express board" (for instance) and the kernel had compiled-in data structures to tell it where the devices were for each board that it supported. As the transition to device tree progressed, boards were converted one by one, and sometimes a few devices at a time, so what exactly the situation was for any specific kernel version depends on which board you're using.

The other thing that I rather suspect you're  running into is that if the kernel crashes early in bootup (ie before it finds the serial port at all) then it will never output anything. So if the kernel is just too early to support the "virt" board properly at all, or if your kernel config is missing something important, then the chances are good that it crashes in early boot without being able to print you a useful message. (Sometimes "earlycon" or "earlyprintk" kernel arguments can assist here, but not always.)

Comment: I think `earlyprintk` needs DEBUG_LL which is compile time.  It is similar to the comments above.  I guess QEMU has code to emulate a serial port (hardware bank) for the boards.

Comment: Yes, QEMU emulates serial ports. But the location in the physical address space of the serial port varies from board to board. DEBUG_LL definitely hard-codes addresses for the serial port and will crash if run on the wrong hardware. I think that some earlyprintk work does not require DEBUG_LL, though (or perhaps that's earlycon?)

Comment: [This commit](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?h=v5.3-rc1&id=c7c3eac6277bc60fb4472a16c5af5d54afc83596) as well as [arch/arm/Kconfig.debug](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/arch/arm/Kconfig.debug?h=v5.3-rc1#n1888) seem to say DEBUG_LL is required.  I saw the original 'earlyprintk' patch and it was polled I/O to a PC serial port as well.  [Here](https://patchwork.kernel.org/patch/7538971/) they are suggesting earlycon so perhaps that is the better choice.  Apparently Qemu emulates a pl101.

Comment: Yeah, definitely originally earlyprintk wanted LL_DEBUG, but I think that might have been improved later. QEMU does implement a PL011 but the address of it in the 'virt' board doesn't match say the address in the vexpress-a9 or the address in the versatilepb boards. Wrong address -> kernel crashes.

Comment: So it seems like the best option for correcting this would be to recompile the kernel to have a DEBUG_LL value that matches the address the virt board uses for its serial and work from there? This is all hoping that it isn't entirely crashing before serial output occurs.

Comment: You should start by finding out what the first version of the kernel that's expected to work with the "virt" board is. Trying anything earlier than that is just never going to work...

Comment: An update to this: I had to sideline this investigation as it was taking up too much time. I appreciate all the comments though! I think I have a somewhat better grasp of how resets generally work after wrangling with two other devices, so when I come back to it I'll try to remember to give an update.